# why my variable lost, after I modified pages in CMS backend editor

Tags: octobercms

Firstly, I have put to string variable in my homepage code section.
Pls check my below screen shot.
[image]

And then, After I open it in my backend system..
When I hit the save button,
mainNavClass = "dark transparent stick-fixed"
topSpacing = "pt-0"
are totally lost, is that filter function newly update feature? Or it's just my setting error? Please advice, Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can not put direct variables there, as its reserved for the CMS it self for its variables and dynamic field variables. [ plus plugin component settings ]

> **Solution**

you can add your variables in `code` section

```
function onStart() {
   $this['mainNavClass'] = 'dark transparent stick-fixed';
   $this['topSpacing'] = 'pt-0';    
}
```

[image]

> **Problem was**

As its space CMS in-build fields and fields which we extend, there for CMS stores `url, metadata info` etc ... so when you save page it will override that portion with its data and **it has no clue you added variables there so it will just rewrite all stuff all again so your data will be lost**

[image]

> it stores `page field data` and `data related to added plugin components`

if any doubts please comment.

Comment: Thank you, that’s really helpful